# meteor event when using on change event, returns nothing

Tags: meteor

when an event is created like below, I wish to know if there has been no change in the event.

```
'change #id'(e){
     if(change){
        do this
     } else {
        do something else
     }
 }
```

In current situation when there is no change than the event returns nothing .

Comment: What do you mean by 'change in the event'? Please elaborate what you are trying to achieve and how what you have tried is meant to accomplish it. Note that `change` is likely to be undefined inside your handler.

Comment: `change` is an event, not a variable. If the event fires there was a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to detect change on **textbox** at keyboard interact from user, we can use `keyup` :

> HTML

```
<input name='id' id='id' type='text'>
```

> JS

```
'keyup #id': function (e, tpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         // Do Your Code If ENTER
    } else {
         // Others code here
    } 
  },
```

If you want change on Select Option like Combobox, use change to detect if user choose from list :

> HTML

```
<select name='id' id='id'>
    <option></option>
    {{#each dataOPTION}}
        <option value="{{_id}}">{{nameOptions}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

> JS

```
'change #id': function (e, tpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Your code here
},
```

I hope this is what you want, like @masterAM says, your question is not clear. But Iam figure out what you want. 
GBU